# Being in Passive

Tags: passive-voice

Is this a passive sentence?

> Being loved is more important!

I don't see it as a passive sentence because there is no subject here. Can someone explain me?

Comment: The subject is the non-finite clause "being loved". Yes, even though "love" is a stative verb, the clause is still passive. Note also the possibility of adding a passive _by_ phrase, cf. "Being loved by someone is more important".

Comment: _Being loved_ is passive, but the full sentence is not passive. (Yes, that sentence has a subject, which is _being loved_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not passive. The main verb "is" links the subject "Being loved" to an adjective complement  "more important".

"Being loved" is a gerund/participle.  It is the gerund form of the verb phrase "is loved" and "is loved" can be seen as a passive form of "love", but you can also treat it as an adjective.